# Can I do research in Nanomedicine provided I am a sophomore in chemical Engineering?

Tags: peer-review, research-undergraduate, engineering, literature-review, review-articles

I want to write a Review Paper on Polymer-Based Nanomedicine, but I’am bit confused weather I should proceed, because much of the terminology used is related to Biology not Engineering.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Unfortunately, we cannot possibly answer your question because we do not know your level of knowledge and it’s very unlikely that any user here is familiar with both fields (also see [this Meta post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734)). You may ask **how** to make this decision, but for this purpose, we would need to know more about your motivations to write a review in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you need to ask this question here I think the answer is no: you are not ready to write a review on this subject.

On the other hand, you are free to learn the "biological terminology" and then write your review, in which case your question would not have been necessary.